# What is the easiest way to check if in a collection everything is empty after a given index?

Tags: c#

What's the easiest way to check if after an index  there is only empty content.

```
string[] tab = {"a","b","c","","",""}
```

for example  `Check(tab[2])` will be true `Check(tab[1])` will be false.

can I do it with lambda expression tab.XXX  without a loop ?

Comment: Your question title says "fastest way" and your question text says "easiest way". Which do you want?

Comment: A loop somewhere will be always present

Comment: Does it need to be `Check(tab[2])` or is `Check(2)` possible? Then it could be `tab.Skip(2).All(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));`

Comment: I don't want to use a loop , that's all

Comment: @user1187282 I'm afraid you'll have to use some loops, directly or indirectly

Comment: @user1187282 LINQ also uses loops, it just hides them from the programer

Comment: Fastest *to write/to read/to understand* would be the answer in Renés comment, so use that. Fastest *to execute* might be hand-optimized unsafe code. Pro tip: Only invest time (and sacrifice readability) for the latter after you have identified this to be the bottleneck of your application. You know what they say about premature optimization...

Comment: @RenéVogt thanks it works !! that's what i needed

Comment: Not wanting to use a loop, should be a fail from any course or school.

Comment: @comments: i have renamed the title to match the description and what OP actuallly needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want a simple and readable way.

You can use `Skip` and `All` (note: not using the index but item-count):

```
bool emptyAfter = tab.Skip(2).All(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

But you could also put it into this extension method to reuse it with any type:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool IsEmptyAfter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, int skipItems, Func<T, bool> isEmpty = null)
    {
        if(isEmpty == null) isEmpty = x => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, default(T));
        return seq.Skip(skipItems).All(x => isEmpty(x));
    }
}
```

---

```
bool emptyAfter = tab.IsEmptyAfter(2, string.IsNullOrEmpty);
```

Comment: `bool emptyAfter = !tab.Skip(2).Any(x => x.Length > 0)` as an option

Comment: @aepot: Yes, but it doesn't make a difference, both, `All` and `Any` are short-circuiting(returning as soon as possible). I prefer `All` because it does not need to reverse the logic and because it matches with the name of the method/requirement.

Comment: True. I guess the really fastest way is `unsafe` way going through pointers and checking in-memory `string` length, in a `for`/`while` loop. But i guess there would be no sensitive difference in performance for array of less than 100k items.

Comment: @aepot: i'm sure that it's micro optimizing in most cases and OP also didn't want the most efficient way but the most readable that he can remember. He also mentioned lambda, so i think he was looking for a LINQ solution.

Comment: I was guided by a title writing that. The answer it perfect, anyway.

Comment: @aepot: renamed the title to match the question description